# How can I identify/type guard DOM elements dynamically

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types, typescript-class

Is there a way for me to set a condition that evaluates the type of a variable?

I know I can use `as` to assert when I call the function to make typescript happy. But that doesn't give me the safety I'm seeking.

I want to type guard to make sure my element is a specific HTMLElement type. I'm trying to build a generic function that wraps around `document.querySelector`. It would accept a selector string and a Type to check against as arguments.

#### Attempting =>

I tried passing in the Type as a type argument, but I don't know how to evaluate the type.

```
function getElement<T extends HTMLElement>(selector: string, type: string): T {
  const el: T | null = document.querySelector(selector);

  if (!el || (typeof el !== T)) {
    throw new Error('Element does not exist');
  }
  return el;
}

const unit: HTMLInputElement = getElement<HTMLInputElement>('#unitToggle', '')
//type argument makes typescript happy but doesn't typeguard.
```

Next, realizing DOM types are built off the classes, I could use `instanceof`. So I tried:

```
function getElement<T extends HTMLElement>(selector: string, type: string): T {
  const el: T | null = document.querySelector(selector);

  if (!el || el instanceof type) {
    throw new Error('Element does not exist');
  }
  return el;
}

const unit: HTMLInputElement = getElement('#unitToggle', 'HTMLInputElement')
```

But I don't know how to pass a class ?definition? as an argument? How can I dynamically type guard my DOM elements?

Comment: `instanceof` works with the class itself, not with its name (a `string`). It would have to be `getElement('#unitToggle', HTMLInputElement)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the operator [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to validate the selected element, you'll need to require that the caller provides the class of the expected element. You can use the type utility [`InstanceType<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) in order to derive the type of element from the class constructor type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQKIBtUFtVhQA8AUAJDYDCCAzlAE4jRz2KoAeUBAJjYmKgDuiABTkyAOikAHAIb1ZuGgC5EssAE8A2gF1yASkQBeAHyIAEgBUAsgBlseAlAA0JEyJqoczeqrr0YMGRnRB9VKloGJigWfVUASTA6dQhUSw1pVCIIpKifMwBvcghItixjRG44CBB8QgkARxBUeg0AZS9UHyJE5Mg0jKyc-2iWE3dPbxj6fQBuchhgUS9EQL7UuCWfQ3p0EHokL3myKAALejhhAWEMegv6EQAiBzqoSrhUPjA4N44YOkecxIAF8SCQSrlEOAYG8jCh0C8nE8AMTQqCWODIZA4R4hKx2RLSECYHCvIEAenJiGpiAAegB+EhAA)

```ts
function getElement<
  ElConstructor extends new (
    ...params: any[]
  ) => HTMLElement,
>(selector: string, ctor: ElConstructor): InstanceType<ElConstructor> {
  const el = document.querySelector<InstanceType<ElConstructor>>(selector);
  if (el instanceof ctor) return el;
  throw new Error("Element does not exist");
}

const unit = getElement("#unitToggle", HTMLInputElement);
//    ^? const unit: HTMLInputElement
```

Comment: Amazing! this resolved it and I learned a bit!